# How to wrap all references to enums in SWIG Java target?

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have an enum `myEnum`, and the following methods in C++:

```
void MyClass::SetValue(myEnum newValue);
void MyClass::GetValue(myEnum& theValue);
```

I'm using the "enums.i", and `myEnum` has properly been converted to a Java `enum`. `SetValue` works correctly, but `GetValue` takes one of the strange SWIGTYPE_p_myEnum_ptr classes that I cannot create.

Is there a way of automatically creating a wrapper for all `enum` references? Something like a class that contains the enum value, so it can be passed around and modified?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Swig docs re typemaps ([section 10.1.1 of SWIG 3](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Arguments_nn3), in particular), there is a typemap that automatically exposes a `void f(T&)` as a `T f()`, you have to tell SWIG to use it for your type. You would use `%apply` of the `OUTPUT` typemap on your type, something along the lines of

```
%apply MyEnum& OUTPUT {MyEnum& theValue};
```

Comment: That will be awesome, but the closest thing I've found in the documentation is http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_using_typemaps_return_arguments.

Do you remember where you saw that?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't get a notification with your update. Anyway, thanks for that, although it's similar to what I already had, but I'm using int* instead of MyEnum& because doing what you said gets me `Warning 453: Can't apply (MyEnum &OUTPUT). No typemaps are defined.` Also, this doesn't change the void to the return type, but it changes the parameter to be the specified type, so I don't think this will really work.